# Why can't style be a plain string in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know that in React JSX `style` attribute must be an object. But I'm wondering why it can't be a plain string like normal HTML.
JSX is compiled to normal HTML by `React.createElement` under the hood.

```
React.createElement("div", {style:"color: red;"}, "Why does this throw an error?")
```

Why doesn't style get added to the element like any other normal HTML attribute?

Answer (score 1):

It could, but it would require some extra code.
https://egghead.io/lessons/css-style-html-with-javascript-template-strings-and-objects-in-css-in-js
I guess the first question is, if it's really worth it.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I technically want to know why style *MUST* be an object. I'm not looking for workarounds.

Comment: You are wondering why it can't be a string under the hood according to your original post. I'm simply demonstrating that it can, but obviously the dev team has chosen a different solution for a reason. You'll have to ask them about their considerations. Sorry I can't answer that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but the video you suggested is converting a style object to string and create a CSS class. My question was about `style` attribute. I exactly want to know the reason behind this limitation.

Comment: Other way around - a template literal string is converted into an object literal. 

You can read here in the documentation: "This is consistent with the DOM style JavaScript property, is more efficient, and prevents XSS security holes."
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

What I said before, was that it's a choice of the dev team, who made this API and they've have based their decision on topics such as performance, security, best practices, etc. You'll have to ask the dev team to get accurate information. Or gather information in the docs :)

Comment: Yes that seems to be a dev team decision, I wanted to know why they did that. I doubt that using objects is far more efficient than plain strings, if it is at all (or is it?!) and for security and XSS it could be true for any other attribute but this limitation is imposed on `style`. Yeah I should find the dev team I think!!